# wrong content type on blob cant open img / file is damaged

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, download, blob

I am trying to download a File using the JS Blob() function, but i cannot open it. It is not clear what type beforehand as I got a filelist, the user can choose what to download. Mac says, that the format might be damaged and that it cannot open that file.

The cURL response I have, from which i create a blob is a binary string (at least i believe so because when i dump it, you see only random symbols and characters, as when you open an image with the text editor)

Here is the [Image code](https://jsfiddle.net/fpx3j4gv/) as I have it via response from my cURL

and here is my code to download this Image.

```
                var a;
            a = document.createElement('a');

            a.href = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([JSON.stringify(response)]));

           // here i tried with and without JSON.stringify
           // also tried new Blob([JSON.stringify(response)],{type:'image/jpeg'}) or with * instead of jpeg, nothing works. Does anybody happen to know what mistake i am doing?

            a.download = data.data.name;
            a.style.display = 'none';
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();
```

Been struggling with this for a few days now, any help is appreciated.

Also when i (in Mac Terminal) do the following command :

```
file test.jpeg
```

it returns

```
test.jpeg: data
```

Best Regards

EDIT: My PHP Code

$ch = curl_init();

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://myapi.com/webapp/api/v1/document/id/" . $id . "/download");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('AuthenticationToken:' . $token));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);


curl_close($ch);
echo $output;
```

Comment: Can you provide the content of the response or an example of what it looks like?

Comment: if you click on the highlighted "image code" and download the txt file, then you see the long content of the file , thats the only thing i get back

Comment: This link crashed

Comment: I put in a new link now to a jsfiddle showing the content

Comment: Am I getting it right that you are trying to transfer binary data using a Unicode string?

Comment: where can i check this? Im actually just trying to "download file with the content text provided by the curl"
Edit: I provided the PHP Code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to serialize the image data to base64 string and pass it to the client

```php
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://myapi.com/webapp/api/v1/document/id/" . $id . "/download");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("AuthenticationToken:" . $token));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);

$contentType = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);

curl_close($ch);

$base64 = "data:/" . $contentType . ";base64," . base64_encode($output);

echo $base64;
```

It this case, on your client side you just need to put the response text for the href like this:

```js
const a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = response;
a.download = data.data.name;
a.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
```

Comment: ill try playing around with the content type and come back here with a result. thanks a ton andy, really!